# « Effectif au service de » : quel est le sens de « effectif » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Quand on écrit « Effectif au service du CNED : 2200 personnes », qu'est-ce que ça signifie ?

Je ai trouvé cette expression sur [une page du site du CNED](http://www.cned.fr/le-cned/institution/presentation/) mais je ne comprends pas de quoi il s'agit. Est-ce qu'il est indiqué que 2200 personnes sont inscrites au CNED ou que 2200 personnes travaillent au CNED ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Effectif" est un synonyme pour "Personnel" ou "Employés". Donc, en disant qu'ils sont "au service", on dit effectivement que ces personnes travaillent au CNED.

Comment: Équipage (pour un bateau).

Answer (score 0):

« Au service » prouve qu'ils y travaillent, sinon on aurait dit « dans le service ».

Comment: « Dans le service » peut également signifier qu'ils y travaillent. P.ex. « Je travaille dans le service de comptabilité de ma banque. » Dans ce contexte, je pense que le mot « service » suffit à dire qu'ils y travaillent, surtout combiné avec le nom « effectif ». Sans ça, on aurait probablement parlé du « nombre de personnes enregistrées ».

Comment: C'est correct merci

Answer (score 0):

Il s'agit d'un substantif. Voir CNRTL: http://cnrtl.fr/definition/effectif

Terme d'administration militaire, et par extension, de **tout groupe d'individus dénombrables**.

On emploie le singulier ou le pluriel.

S'agissant de la plaquette institutionnelle qui précise *au service de*, il s'agit des **personnes affectées à, travaillant, ou comptabilisées comme telles**, et pas les *clients* du CNED (étudiants, inscrits), appelés *Public CNED* sur cette page : http://www.cned.fr/le-cned/institution/chiffres-cned/.

Dans un autre contexte, le même mot aurait pu s'employer pour les étudiants.